# Sql Server Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I have two sql server S1(2008) and S2(2005).

S2 is added to S1 as linked server.

S2 have a table Product.

When I try to run the code

```
select ProductID from Product
```

I get the error:

```
Location:    rmt_meta.cpp:347
Expression:  fFalse
SPID:        71
Process ID:  3828
Description:     Unknown column in remote index! Skipping.
```

Any idea?

Comment: That is not an error from SQL Server error.  There must something else going on here that you're not telling us.

Comment: What tool were you using to execute your SQL command?  And what did you use to see that error?

Comment: Studio Server Management Studio

Answer (score 1):

This [KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2644794) is the closest thing I can find regarding your error, *that would come from SQL Server*. I would see if you could find any other errors that may give you more explanation as to the issue. Since this seems to be dealing with XML data I cannot help you that much, have not worked with XML much. Other folks on this forum might be able to chime in though...

Comment: This was my last option on my list, thank you. 
I'm glad I did not use this option.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. I dropped all indexes and then recreate them again.
DBCC CHECKDB, etc gives me no warnings, no error.

Comment: Yeah I guess since the error did reference an index it might have something to do with that...